# How do I set the Name of Net Named Pipes in WCF when hosted in ASP .NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, iis, named-pipes

First a bit of background:

I have a web server which runs 4 instances of the same ASP .NET application each one in a different culture (set in the web.config). The cultures are British (GBR), Australian (AUS), Irish (IRL), and New Zealander (NZL). Each of them has a webmethod "DoWork" which I would like to call via a single scheduled task. I have a simple exe which calls this method on each of the four cultures, simplified code:

```
Dim AUSclient As New AUSAutomated.AUSAutomatedClient()
AUSclient.DoWork
Dim GBRclient As New GBRAutomated.GBRAutomatedClient()
GBRclient.DoWork
Dim IRLclient As New IRLAutomated.IRLAutomatedClient()
IRLclient.DoWork
Dim NZLclient As New NZLAutomated.NZLAutomatedClient()
NZLclient.DoWork
```

In the task which is consuming the methods the app.config looks like this:

```
        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Services/GBR/GBRAutomated.svc"
            binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IGBRAutomated"
            contract="GBRAutomated.IGBRAutomated" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IGBRAutomated">
                </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Services/IRL/IRLAutomated.svc"
 binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IIRLAutomated"
 contract="IRLAutomated.IIRLAutomated" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IIRLAutomated">
                    </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Services/NZL/NZLAutomated.svc"
            binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_INZLAutomated"
            contract="NZLAutomated.INZLAutomated" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_INZLAutomated">
                    </endpoint>
```

The application exposes the web method via WCF using a net named pipes binding. Each of the cultures has an entry in the web.config to point to the correct service. For example the Ireland one is:

```
<service name="Web.IRLAutomated">
            <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Services/IRL/IRLAutomated.svc" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="Web.IIRLAutomated" />
        </service>
```

So the exposed method for each culture has a different contract and address.

When the task runs it calls the Australian Method all 4 times. It seems to ignore the settings in the web.configs and call the method with the correct contract on the first application. So my question is:

**How can I set a unique pipe name for the method in each culture?**

I tried setting hostNameComparisonMode="Exact" on the binding but this doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You Can't**

After some searching I found a similiar question on StackOverflow here:

[controlling the name of a named pipe when hosting WCF net.pipe binding in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806430/controlling-the-name-of-a-named-pipe-when-hosting-wcf-net-pipe-binding-in-iis)

As no one has answered the above question in 2 years I'm assuming what am I trying to do is impossible.

If anyone else is struggling with this sort of problem I found this blog entry very helpful in helping me understand:

http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2008/05/19/exploring-the-wcf-named-pipe-binding-part-1.aspx

I am going to change the binding to http which will solve my problem.