# How to host net named pipe binding enabled wcf application in iis?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, named-pipes, netnamedpipebinding

I have a following configuration in my wcf service

```
    <endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" 
          contract="WcfWithNamedPipe.IService1" 
          bindingConfiguration="WcfWithNamedPipe.netNamedPipeBinding">
    </endpoint>
```

can any one suggest me how to host this wcf service in iis using netNamedPipe binding?

Comment: It should be possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806430/controlling-the-name-of-a-named-pipe-when-hosting-wcf-net-pipe-binding-in-iis. Are you getting an error or is it just not working?

Comment: First, try with a simple binding like basicHttp. This will ensure that your service is valid. After, you have to add a new protocol NET.TCP for your site (in Advanced Properties) and then  also add a new binding in your website.

Answer (score 5):

To get Named pipes to work on IIS you must enable Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) on IIS and configure the site that you are using to allow named pipes.

For details see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752253.aspx

Like Cybermax says in the comment it is a good idea to get it to work with basic http binding first.

If you get to the point where you think that you have setup everything correctly and it still does not work, check the firewall settings.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Named Pipe Activation. In Windows 8 (and probably beyond?), open the "*Turn Windows features on or off*" window, and locate and check the following:

[image]

You also need to specify the net.pipe protocol for the application in IIS. Right click the node for the application, select *Manage Application* and *Advanced Settings...*. Here you will probably have `http` under *enabled protocolls*. Add `, net.pipe` after it and click OK to save it.

[image: Adding net.pipe in IIS]

If everything else is correct, this should allow a call to a service to cause the service to be activated.