# WCF exception 'net.pipe' protocol is disabled for the site temporarily

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration

I'm having exception in event viewer. The exception is wcf related.

```
An error occurred in the Activation Service 'NetPipeActivator' of the protocol 'net.pipe' while trying to listen for the site '2', thus the protocol is disabled for the site temporarily. See the exception message for more details.
 URL: WeakWildcard:net.pipe://Pc4/
 Status: ConflictingRegistration
 Exception: 
 Process Name: SMSvcHost
 Process ID: 1724
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Related question: [How to host net named pipe binding enabled wcf application in iis?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12375902/9363973)

Comment: already done this and firewall is disabled

Comment: FYI the OS is wndows server 2012 r2 and net.pip is enabled Win process activation is also enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can’t have two websites in IIS that have the same net named pipe binding. Because the netnamdpipebinding mechanism service can only receive calls from the same machine, the pipe name is the unique identifier string for the pipe address. We can only open one named pipe on the same machine, so two named pipe addresses cannot share the same pipe name on the same machine.